# How can I make a command to write out the solution of the absolute value inequality?

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

I've written this source code, but I can't finish it yet.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[Plot[a Abs[x - h] + k, {x, -10, 10}], 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> {500, 400}
 ],
 {{a, 1, Style["a", Italic]}, -5, 5, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{h, 0, Style["h", Italic]}, -5, 5, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{k, 0, Style["k", Italic]}, -5, 5, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
]
```

Comment: I think you'll need to explain your question better. The code seems to plot graphs of various absolute value functions. But I don't see any inequalities here, or anything that needs to be solved. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   Plot[a Abs[x - h] + k, {x, -10, 10},
    PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}},
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
    AspectRatio -> 1,
    ImageSize -> {500, 400},
    AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"x", "y"}),
    Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
      Point[{h, k}]}],
   StringForm["\nx = ``, y = ``",
    NumberForm[h, {3, 2}], NumberForm[k, {3, 2}]]},
  Alignment -> Center],
 {{a, 1, Style["a", Italic]}, -5, 5, .01,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{h, 0, Style["h", Italic]}, -5, 5, .01,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{k, 0, Style["k", Italic]}, -5, 5, .01,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

EDIT:  Note that in the `Solve`, `Abs[a x + b]` is replaced by the equivalent (for real-valued functions) `Sqrt[(a x + b)^2]`

```
Manipulate[
 pts = {x, e x + f} /. Solve[Sqrt[(a x + b)^2] + c x + d == e x + f, x];
 Column[{
   Plot[{Abs[a x + b] + c x + d, e x + f},
    {x, -10, 10},
    Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5],
      Point[pts]},
    ImageSize -> 360,
    PlotLegends ->
     Placed[
      {Abs[a x + b] + c x + d, e x + f},
      Below]],
   StringForm["Intercepts = ``",
    NumberForm[pts // N, {4, 2}]]},
  Alignment -> Center],
 {{a, 2, Style["a", Italic]},
  -5, 5, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 0, Style["b", Italic]},
  -5, 5, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{c, 0, Style["c", Italic]},
  -5, 5, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{d, -3, Style["d", Italic]},
  -5, 5, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{e, 0, Style["e", Italic]},
  -5, 5, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{f, 5, Style["f", Italic]},
  -5, 5, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Bob, you helped me a lot.:) I'm just thinking about how can I complete your code, if I want to model abs(ax+b)+(cx+d)=ex+f.

Comment: @Zauberkerl - see edit above.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[a Abs[x - h] + k, {x, -10, 10}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> {500, 400}
 ],
 {{a, 1, Style["a", Italic]}, -5, 5, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 {{h, 0, Style["h", Italic]}, -5, 5, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 {{k, 0, Style["k", Italic]}, -5, 5, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Alexei, correct me if I'm wrong, but all you've done is removed the redundant `Show` from the OP's code. Your code achieves the same result as the OP's though. Perhaps this should be a comment rather than an answer, or you may want to state explicitly what changes you have made to the code.

Comment: @MarcoB  You are right. All I wrote: "Try this"